# Overriding remote git repository with my local repository using ssh

Tags: git, ssh

I have a remote repository git on a server which contains a project, and I want to replace all files within it by all files from the local project file.

I want to do that with ssh command, so what is exactly the right things to do?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about if you push your local project files to GitHub/BitBucket etc then, pull/reset the changes into your remote repository server?

Comment: I can't because i have no privilege to do that. i can use only ssh to do that on a remote server .

Answer (score 0):

Secure Copy a file from local to remote machine:

```
$ scp <file> <username>@<IP address or hostname>:<Destination>
```

Send a Project Folder:

```
scp -r /path/to/project/ <user>@<ip>:/path/to/destination/folder/
```

[More about SSH File Transfer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles)